# Can you buy a downloadable version of OS X Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, mac

Can you buy a downloadable version of the latest OS X? I can't seem to find it but it seems like should have it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Snow Leopard does not sell a downloadable version. OS X 10.7 Lion will be sold via download from the Mac App Store, but that OS is not released until July.

Comment: ...although the Mac App Store requires Snow Leopard, so you're going to need at least one more physical system disk.